# insert a link into a react-tooltip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, tooltip

I am trying to set a link inside of a react-tooltip and instead of getting back a link, `[Object object]` is coming back into the tooltip. The format I am using is setting the link as the `data-tip` like this:

```
<div data-place="right" data-type="dark" data-effect="solid" data-multiline="false" data-class="nav-tooltip" data-tip={link} delayHide={1000}>
   <div>view</div>
 </div>
 <ReactTooltip />
```

I am confused as to why this doesn't work. I have tried string interpolation and no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using getContent on ReactTooltip like this:

```
<MenuItem data-tip="Shouldn't show this" data-for="tooltip">

<ReactTooltip id="tooltip" event="focus" getContent={() => {
                            return <div>Test</div>
                        }}/>
```

The documentation shows this possibility: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip

Note: if you have data-html={true} then it will return [Object object] as well

Edit: I think if you want to make a full html box out of a tooltip, then you'd better find a different plugin. Tooltip's shouldn't be used for full html right?

Answer (score 0):

when you are using react-tooltip you need to set html={true} it is in their doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip

```
<ReactTooltip html={true} />
```

and then in your css file do this

```
.__react_component_tooltip {
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```

Refer
https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip/issues/336